# Retirar repetidos

Tags: javascript, array

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
  var e = Array (10,20,30,40, 50);

  for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {

    for (j = 0; j < e.length; j++) {

      if (i == e[j]) document.write ("O numero escolhido é: " + i + "<br />");
      else document.write ("O numero NÃO escolhido é: " + i + "<br />");

    }   

  }
```

A intenção aqui é listar assim:

```
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 0
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 1
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 2
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 3
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 4
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 5
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 6
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 7
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 8
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 9
O numero escolhido é: 10

....


O numero NÃO escolhido é: 11
...
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 19
O numero escolhido é: 20
...
```

Acontece que o que está acontecendo é:

```
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 0
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 0
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 0
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 0
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 0
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 1
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 1
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 1
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 1
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 1
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 2
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 2
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 2
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 2
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 2
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 3
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 3
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 3
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 3
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 3
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 4
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 4
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 4
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 4
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 4
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 5
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 5
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 5
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 5
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 5
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 6
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 6
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 6
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 6
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 6
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 7
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 7
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 7
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 7
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 7
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 8
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 8
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 8
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 8
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 8
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 9
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 9
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 9
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 9
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 9
O numero escolhido é: 10
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 10
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 10
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 10
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 10
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 11
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 11
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 11
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 11
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 11
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 12
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 12
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 12
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 12
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 12
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 13
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 13
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 13
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 13
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 13
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 14
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 14
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 14
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 14
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 14
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 15
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 15
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 15
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 15
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 15
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 16
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 16
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 16
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 16
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 16
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 17
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 17
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 17
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 17
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 17
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 18
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 18
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 18
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 18
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 18
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 19
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 19
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 19
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 19
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 19
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 20
O numero escolhido é: 20
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 20
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 20
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 20
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 21
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 21
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 21
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 21
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 21
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 22
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 22
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 22
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 22
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 22
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 23
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 23
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 23
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 23
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 23
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 24
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 24
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 24
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 24
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 24
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 25
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 25
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 25
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 25
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 25
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 26
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 26
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 26
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 26
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 26
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 27
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 27
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 27
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 27
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 27
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 28
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 28
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 28
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 28
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 28
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 29
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 29
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 29
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 29
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 29
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 30
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 30
O numero escolhido é: 30
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 30
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 30
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 31
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 31
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 31
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 31
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 31
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 32
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 32
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 32
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 32
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 32
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 33
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 33
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 33
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 33
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 33
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 34
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 34
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 34
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 34
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 34
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 35
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 35
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 35
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 35
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 35
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 36
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 36
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 36
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 36
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 36
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 37
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 37
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 37
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 37
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 37
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 38
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 38
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 38
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 38
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 38
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 39
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 39
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 39
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 39
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 39
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 40
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 40
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 40
O numero escolhido é: 40
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 40
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 41
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 41
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 41
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 41
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 41
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 42
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 42
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 42
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 42
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 42
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 43
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 43
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 43
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 43
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 43
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 44
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 44
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 44
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 44
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 44
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 45
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 45
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 45
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 45
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 45
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 46
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 46
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 46
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 46
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 46
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 47
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 47
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 47
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 47
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 47
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 48
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 48
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 48
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 48
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 48
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 49
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 49
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 49
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 49
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 49
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 50
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 50
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 50
O numero NÃO escolhido é: 50
O numero escolhido é: 50
```

Como seria contornar esse problema?

Comment: Pesquise por `Array.prototype.includes`, ele substituirá o seu laço de repetição interno.

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo

Answer (score 4):

O algoritmo precisa varrer o segundo laço para saber se pelo menos um encaixa, não pode imprimir direto, o objetivo do segundo laço é apenas saber se tem um elemento dentro do outro ou não, no momento que ele acha deve encerrar o laço e aí sim decidir se vai imprimir. Se varrer todo o laço não deve imprimir. Isso pode ser feito com o uso de *flags*, mas eu acho isso ruim e fazer em uma função separada é melhor, por isso foi assim que fiz. Se fizer de uma forma genérica é possível usar esta função em todo lugar.

```js
function testa(e, i) {
    for (var j = 0; j < e.length; j++) if (e[j] == i) return true;
    return false;
}
var e = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
for (var i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
    if (testa(e, i)) document.write("O numero escolhido é: " + i + "<br />");
    else document.write("O numero NÃO escolhido é: " + i + "<br />");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Unique.js).

Answer (score 3):

Como comentado, você pode substituir a lógica do laço de repetição interno pela chamada do método `includes` do *array*:

```js
const numbers = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50];

for (let i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
  let no = numbers.includes(i) ? '' : 'NÃO';
  console.log(`O número ${no} escolhido foi: ${i}`);
}
```